# return a const and non const wrapper object

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, const-iterator

If I want a custom container class to give access to its data through an iterator-like object (actually acting as a wrapper for some data in the container) and I want to be able to get both a const and a non const iterator-like object, one allowing only reading and one reading and writing, so I have to implement two different iterator-like objects; one which allows only reading and one which allows reading and writing, or can I wrap this functionality in one single object.

The issue is that I have to return this object by value but I cannot return a by-value object which cannot directly be put into a non const variable like

```
const accessor container::getConstAccessor(){/**/}
```

being misused like

```
accessor a=myContainer.getConstAccessor(); //effectively giving me a non const
```

The only solution I can see is to have two accessor classes/structs. One which acts const and one which acts readWrite, regardless of wether they are in a const or non const variable.

This emulates perhaps a constIterator and iterator, but is this truly needed? Can you not make *one* accessor and return either a const or non const version from the container?

I tried rephrasing this question a few times, to make it most general, but if it makes sense, I am not entirely certain. I hope it does.

Comment: if you make it non-copyable, one cannot get a non-const instance from a const one (except for a nasty `const_cast`)

Comment: Thing about why STL classes (e.g. `std::vector`) implements `const_iterator`, and `iterator` as two distinct classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can you not make one accessor and return either a const or non const version from the container?

Not really. Firstly, you need two accessors as you have to detect whether or not `*this` is `const`-qualified:

```
/* ??? */ my_container::getAccessor();
/* ??? */ my_container::getAccessor() const;
```

Then, if you're returning by value, you have no way of forcing the caller of `getAccessor` to store the return value in a `const` variable. That's why you need two different types if you want to enforce immutability in the `const`-qualified accessor:

```
accessor my_container::getAccessor();
const_accessor my_container::getAccessor() const;
```

---

Code repetition can very likely be avoided by implementing both `accessor` and `const_accessor` in terms of some template `accessor_impl<T>` class that can be instantiated with `T`/`const T`.

Comment: You might want to add that it should be possible to implement them both using a template instantiated with either `T` or `const T` (for whatever `T` makes sense internally).

Comment: Thanks to all who responded. In the end it was perhaps too flimsy a question, but in the end I did as suggested and made two distinct accessors. I will mark this as the answer.